# Commands in math

Tags: tables, math-mode, graphics

I have some commands as follows, but it doesn't work to run my LaTeX file. Is there any wrong order in these commands?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,arydshln}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsrefs,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{kbordermatrix,amsthm,rotating,array}
%\usepackage{amsmath,kbordermatrix,blkarray}
%\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}
%\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, colorlinks, plainpages]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red, anchorcolor=green, citecolor=cyan, urlcolor=red, filecolor=magenta, pdftoolbar=true}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{array}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}

%Me
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\newcommand\bigzero{\makebox(0,0){\text{\huge0}}}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tabularx,rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[section]
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You load the the `graphicx` package no fewer than three [3!] times, with differing options. This cannot possibly end well.

Comment: Okay, I omitted 2 of them. But still doesn't work. Is there any other hint?